# Keyword mapping for sub document in elastic NEST

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I learn now Nest 6.x client for elasticsearch  I want to use term search in sub documents. I have this classes:

```
public class BaseTest
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public SubBase SubDocument { get; set; }

        public Guid TypeId { get; set; }

        public string BaseTitel { get; set; }
    }
public class SubBase
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Guid IdGuid { get; set; }
        public string Titel { get; set; }
    }
```

and use this mapping to create an index:

```
.Mappings(mp => mp
                    .Map<BaseTest>(m => m
                        .Properties(pr => pr
                            .Keyword(kw => kw
                                .Name(nm => nm.BaseTitel)))
                        .Properties(pr => pr
                            .Keyword(kw => kw
                                .Name(nm => nm.TypeId)))
                        .Properties(pr => pr
                            .Keyword(kw => kw
                                .Name(nm => nm.SubDocument.Titel)))
                        .Properties(pr => pr
                            .Keyword(kw => kw
                                .Name(nm => nm.SubDocument.IdGuid)
                            ))))
```

wenn I try to search GUID(or string in GUID format, weil I save SubBase.Titel as Guid for tests) values in BaseTest it works, but not in SubBase.
To search I use this query:

```
.Query(q => q
 .ConstantScore(cs => cs
  .Filter(f => f
   .Term(t => t
    .SubDocument.Titel, "5d511b8a-37c7-40c1-a5c3-4de13e16e379"))))
```

**Update**
New mapping:

```
.Mappings(mp => mp
                    .Map<BaseTest>(m => m
                        .Properties(pr => pr
                            .Keyword(kw => kw
                                .Name(nm => nm.BaseTitel)
                                .Name(nm => nm.TypeId)
                            )
                            .Object<SubBase>(o => o
                                .Name(n => n.SubDocument)
                                .Properties(p => p
                                    .Keyword(k => k
                                        .Name(n => n.Titel)
                                        .Name(n => n.IdGuid)))))))
```

Now I can find Guid properties, but not a propery with type string an value like "5d511b8a-37c7-40c1-a5c3-4de13e16e379"

Comment: Your mapping is not correct. You only need one call to `.Properties()`, then map all fields (`.Keyword()`, `.Text()`, etc) within this. See the mapping documentation for some examples: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/fluent-mapping.html

Comment: @RussCam thanks, now I can find Guid properties. but if this property has a string type in Guid format it will be not found. What should I do?

Comment: > property has a string type in Guid format 
- I don't understand what you mean here. Can you elaborate? `System.Guid` serializes to `string`

Comment: SubBase.Titel = "5d511b8a-37c7-40c1-a5c3-4de13e16e379"

Comment: You should map `SubBase` as an `object` datatype. If all `string` and `Guid` properties should be mapped as `keyword`, you can apply a visitor to set this convention: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/visitor-pattern-mapping.html

Comment: your mapping is still not correct; calls to `.Name(...)` inside `.Keyword()` should be inside their own `.Keyword()` call. Essentially, everything inside **one** `.Keyword()` call is the mapping for **one** field/property.

Comment: Ok, thank you. :-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Russ Cam

```
.Mappings(mp => mp
               .Map<BaseTest>(m => m
                 .Properties(pr => pr
                   .Keyword(kw => kw
                     .Name(nm => nm.BaseTitel))
                   .Keyword(kw => kw
                     .Name(nm => nm.TypeId))
                   .Object<SubBase>(o => o
                     .Name(n => n.SubDocument)
                       .Properties(p => p
                         .Keyword(k => k
                           .Name(n => n.Titel))
                         .Keyword(k => k
                           .Name(n => n.IdGuid)))))))
```